# SSL certificates their public keys and thumbprints

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl

I want to use mTLS, so for testing I created simple API. I wanted to check if I will receive the public key of the certificate after the client sends the certificate to me (the server) as I want to use this public key in future encryption. So I created client certificate with OpenSSL and sent it to my API. I got it in JSON format:

```
{
    "Archived": false,
    "Extensions": [],
    "FriendlyName": "",
    "HasPrivateKey": false,
    "PrivateKey": null,
    "IssuerName": {
        "Name": "E=undefined@undefined.com, CN=ca.localhost, OU=Undefined, O=Undefined, L=Undefined, S=Undefined, C=PL",
        "Oid": {
            "Value": null,
            "FriendlyName": null
        },
        "RawData": "MIGcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJQTDESMBAGA1UECAwJVW5kZWZpbmVkMRIwEAYDVQQHDAlVbmRlZmluZWQxEjAQBgNVBAoMCVVuZGVmaW5lZDESMBAGA1UECwwJVW5kZWZpbmVkMRUwEwYDVQQDDAxjYS5sb2NhbGhvc3QxJjAkBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWF3VuZGVmaW5lZEB1bmRlZmluZWQuY29t"
    },
    "NotAfter": "2049-12-05T08:46:19+01:00",
    "NotBefore": "2022-07-21T09:46:19+02:00",
    "PublicKey": {
        "EncodedKeyValue": {
            "Oid": {
                "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1",
                "FriendlyName": "RSA"
            },
            "RawData": "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"
        },
        "EncodedParameters": {
            "Oid": {
                "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1",
                "FriendlyName": "RSA"
            },
            "RawData": "BQA="
        },
        "Key": {
            "Key": {
                "Algorithm": {
                    "Algorithm": "RSA"
                },
                "AlgorithmGroup": {
                    "AlgorithmGroup": "RSA"
                },
                "ExportPolicy": 0,
                "Handle": {
                    "IsInvalid": false,
                    "IsClosed": false
                },
                "IsEphemeral": true,
                "IsMachineKey": false,
                "KeyName": null,
                "KeySize": 4096,
                "KeyUsage": 16777215,
                "ParentWindowHandle": {
                    "value": 0
                },
                "Provider": {
                    "Provider": "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"
                },
                "ProviderHandle": {
                    "IsInvalid": false,
                    "IsClosed": false
                },
                "UIPolicy": {
                    "ProtectionLevel": 0,
                    "FriendlyName": null,
                    "Description": null,
                    "UseContext": null,
                    "CreationTitle": null
                },
                "UniqueName": null
            },
            "LegalKeySizes": [
                {
                    "MinSize": 512,
                    "MaxSize": 16384,
                    "SkipSize": 64
                }
            ],
            "KeyExchangeAlgorithm": "RSA",
            "SignatureAlgorithm": "RSA",
            "KeySize": 4096
        },
        "Oid": {
            "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1",
            "FriendlyName": "RSA"
        }
    },
    "RawData": "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",
    "SerialNumber": "29E2F3784CCAEF563D112B5CDFFA71B761739E99",
    "SignatureAlgorithm": {
        "Value": "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11",
        "FriendlyName": "sha256RSA"
    },
    "SubjectName": {
        "Name": "E=client.undefined@undefined.com, CN=client.localhost, OU=Undefined, O=Undefined, L=Undefined, S=Undefined, C=PL",
        "Oid": {
            "Value": null,
            "FriendlyName": null
        },
        "RawData": "MIGnMQswCQYDVQQGEwJQTDESMBAGA1UECAwJVW5kZWZpbmVkMRIwEAYDVQQHDAlVbmRlZmluZWQxEjAQBgNVBAoMCVVuZGVmaW5lZDESMBAGA1UECwwJVW5kZWZpbmVkMRkwFwYDVQQDDBBjbGllbnQubG9jYWxob3N0MS0wKwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFh5jbGllbnQudW5kZWZpbmVkQHVuZGVmaW5lZC5jb20="
    },
    "Thumbprint": "9508CCC6D5ABE0E0C2DBD21BA8EEE69D39A5D398",
    "Version": 1,
    "Handle": {
        "value": 1829014818928
    },
    "Issuer": "E=undefined@undefined.com, CN=ca.localhost, OU=Undefined, O=Undefined, L=Undefined, S=Undefined, C=PL",
    "Subject": "E=client.undefined@undefined.com, CN=client.localhost, OU=Undefined, O=Undefined, L=Undefined, S=Undefined, C=PL"
}
```

I wonder if `"RawData"` in `"PublicKey"` is the public key of this certificate. If not, is it included somewhere in that response? Also, is it a good idea to assign certificates to my clients via a thumbprint? Does refreshing the certificate also mean changing the thumbprint?

Comment: *"I created simple API ... I wonder if "RawData" in "PublicKey" is the public key of this certificate. If not, is it included somewhere in that response?"* - since you created the API, so you should be able to tell what the API returns. It is unknown for us to know what exactly your API does.

Comment: There are two questions here: where is the public key from the certificate, and how do certificate thumbprints work. The second is a valid question though almost certainly one asked and answered on this site already (definitely answered elsewhere). The first isn't even a security question - just a programming one! - and belongs on StackOverflow if anywhere (did you try reading the docs for the API you used to parse the certificate?)

Comment: Sorry, I rushed this question and at the same time did not check the documentation of the method that gets the certificate from the request. So the short answer: in this case, "RawData" in "PublicKey" is the public key (HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync() method in ASP NET Core) and the answer to the fingerprint question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119765/will-public-thumbprint-change-on-renewing-a-certificate